# S3 Boto3 Stubber doesn't have mapping for download file?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3, python-3.7, botocore

Currently writing tests and trying to make use of the [`Stubber`](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html) provided by botocore.

I'm trying:

```
client = boto3.client("s3")
response = {'Body': 'content'}
expected_params = {'Bucket': 'a_bucket_name', 'Key': 'a_path', 'Filename': 'a_target'}

with Stubber(client) as stubber:
    stubber.add_response('download_file', response, expected_params)
    download_file(client, "a_bucket_name", "a_path", "a_target")
```

Where that download file is my own function that just wraps the client download_file call. It works in practice.

However, the test fails on the `stubber.add_response` due to a 'OperationNotFound' error. I stepped through using the debugger, and the issue appears here in the stub API:

```
if not hasattr(self.client, method):
    raise ValueError(
        "Client %s does not have method: %s"
        % (self.client.meta.service_model.service_name, method))

# Create a successful http response
http_response = AWSResponse(None, 200, {}, None)

operation_name = self.client.meta.method_to_api_mapping.get(method) <------- Error here
self._validate_response(operation_name, service_response)
```

There doesn't seem to be a mapping between the two in the dictionary, is this a failure of the stub API or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just found this issue, so looks like for once it really is the library and not me:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/974

> That's because download_file and upload_file are customizations which live in boto3. They call out to one or many requests under the hood. Right now there's not a great story for supporting customizations other than recording underlying commands they use and adding them to the stubber. There's an external library that can handle that for you, though we don't support it ourselves.